# Append or copy first in python

Tags: python, recursion, memory-management, copy, append

I am following a dynamic programming course of return a list of number if you can sum up to a target and running into this problem.

Here is my first try:

```
def howSum(target, arr, memo={}):
    if target in memo: return memo[target]
    if target == 0: return []
    if target < 0 : return None

    shortest = None

    for i in arr:
        remainderCombination = howSum(target-i, arr, memo)
        if remainderCombination is not None:
            remainderCombination.append(i)
            combination = remainderCombination.copy()
            
            if (shortest == None or len(shortest) > len(combination)):
                shortest = combination.copy()
    
    memo[target] = shortest
    return shortest


print(howSum(8,[1,2,3,5],{}))
```

which returns the undesirable result of [5, 1, 1, 1].

On my second try, I did like this:

```
def howSum(target, arr, memo={}):
    if target in memo: return memo[target]
    if target == 0: return []
    if target < 0 : return None

    shortest = None

    for i in arr:
        remainderCombination = howSum(target-i, arr, memo)
        if remainderCombination is not None:
            combination = remainderCombination.copy()
            combination.append(i)
            
            if (shortest == None or len(shortest) > len(combination)):
                shortest = combination.copy()
    
    memo[target] = shortest
    return shortest


print(howSum(8,[1,2,3,5],{}))
```

and receive the right result of [5, 3].

So basically I only changed the order of copy() and append() but I do not understand why it resulted in different answer.

**Edit**
So as [@matszwecja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9296093/matszwecja) has commented, this is a generic Python's mutable problem

> Ah yes, of course. "Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default
> Argument

Comment: in first example, you append to `remainderCombination` and then copy it, so both objects have newly appended item. In the 2nd example you copy first, so the item is appended only to copy.

Comment: For each loops both "remainderCombination" and "combination" should be renewed and I only need "combination" to work properly from that breakpoint. Thus, both snippets should yield same results but they did not.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) - are you sure it works as expected?

Comment: Oh, I think this is what I am looking for. Still no clue where exactly is the problem and how to prevent this in the future. Thank you and sorry for not eligible to give you an upvote you deserve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because at first you were appending i to remainderCombination and setting combination equal to it

```
remainderCombination.append(i)
combination = remainderCombination.copy()
```

And in the next snippet you say you just changed the order but it seems you also applied the append on combination rather than remainderCombination

```
combination = remainderCombination.copy()
combination.append(i)
```

Also setting a variable equal to some array and then updating the array causes change only in the array not the copy stored in the other variable.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My point is the elements in "combination" should be the same for both snippet but apparently it is not.